# Converting an Integer value to base64, and then decoding it to get a plaintext

Tags: python, base64

I am given this number 427021005928, which i am supposed to change into a base64 encoded string and then decode the base64 string to get a plain text.

This decimal value 427021005928 when converted to binary gives 110001101101100011011110111010001101000 which corresponds to 'Y2xvdGg=', which is what i want. Got the conversion from (https://cryptii.com/pipes/binary-to-base64)

And then finally i decode 'Y2xvdGg=' to get the text cloth.

My problem is i do not have any idea how to use Python to get from either the decimal or binary value to get 'Y2xvdGg='

Some help would be appreciated!

NOTE: I only have this value 427021005928 at the start. I need to get the base64 and plaintext answers.

Comment: I'm not getting the same base64 string. Try `import base64; import struct; v=struct.pack('L', v); base64.b64encode(struct.pack('L', v))`

Answer (score 4):

One elegant way would be using [[Python 3]: struct - Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct), but given the fact that *Python* numbers are not fixed size, some additional computation would be required (for example, the number is **5** bytes long).

Apparently, the online converter, applied the *base64* encoding on the number's memory representation, which can be obtained via [[Python 3]: int.**to_bytes**(*length, byteorder, *, signed=False*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)(***endianness* is important, and in this case it's *big***):

For the backwards process, reversed steps are required. There are 2 alternatives:

- Things being done manually (this could also be applied to the "forward" process)
- Using `int.from_bytes`

> ```py
> >>> import base64
> >>>
> >>> number = 427021005928
> >>>
> >>> number_bytes = number.to_bytes((number.bit_length() + 7) // 8, byteorder="big")  # Here's where the magic happens
> >>> number_bytes, number_bytes.decode()
> (b'cloth', 'cloth')
> >>>
> >>> encoded = base64.b64encode(number_bytes)
> >>> encoded, encoded.decode()  # Don't let yourself tricked by the variable and method names resemblance
> (b'Y2xvdGg=', 'Y2xvdGg=')
> >>>
> >>> # Now, getting the number back
> ...
> >>> decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
> >>> decoded
> b'cloth'
> >>>
> >>> final_number0 = sum((item * 256 ** idx for idx, item in enumerate(reversed(decoded))))
> >>> final_number0
> 427021005928
> >>> number == final_number0
> True
> >>>
> >>> # OR using from_bytes
> ...
> >>> final_number1 = int.from_bytes(decoded, byteorder="big")
> >>> final_number1
> 427021005928
> >>> final_number1 == number
> True
> ```

For more details on bitwise operations, check [[SO]: Output of crc32b in PHP is not equal to Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712872/output-of-crc32b-in-php-is-not-equal-to-python/54713806#54713806).

Comment: Thank you! Your latest edit finally helped me! Thanks for the magic!

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't carefully read the question at the beginning, and focused on the wrong thing.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes)

```
>>> import base64
>>> x=427021005928
>>> y=x.to_bytes(5,byteorder='big').decode('utf-8')
>>> base64.b64encode(y.encode()).decode()
'Y2xvdGg='
>>> y
'cloth'
```

Comment: Updated the answer @martineau

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: No problem. Please upvote/accept it if it helped you

Comment: Hi @Moud :) Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you, and please also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

try

```
number = 427021005928

encode = base64.b64encode(bytes(number))

decode = base64.b64decode(encodeNumber)
```

Comment: the values of encode and decode don't get printed out for me

Comment: This **doesn't work** in *Python 3*, and also **doesn't match** the question 2nd paragraph! -1.

Answer (score 1):

The function below converts an unsigned 64 bit integer into base64 representation, and back again. This is particularly helpful for encoding database keys.

We first encode the integer into a byte array using little endian, and automatically remove any extra leading zeros. Then convert to base64, removing the unnecessary `=` sign. Note the flag `url_safe` which makes the solution non-base64 compliant, but works better with URLs.

```
def int_to_chars(number, url_safe = True):
    '''
    Convert an integer to base64. Used to turn IDs into short URL slugs.
    :param number:
    :param url_safe: base64 may contain "/" and "+", which do not play well
                     with URLS. Set to True to convert "/" to "-" and "+" to
                     "_". This no longer conforms to base64, but looks better
                     in URLS.
    :return:
    '''
    if number < 0:
        raise Exception("Cannot convert negative IDs.")
    # Encode the long, long as little endian.
    packed = struct.pack("<Q", number)
    # Remove leading zeros
    while len(packed) > 1 and packed[-1] == b'\x00':
        packed = packed[:-1]
    encoded = base64.b64encode(packed).split(b"=")[0]
    if url_safe:
        encoded = encoded.replace(b"/", b"-").replace(b"+", b".")
    return encoded

def chars_to_int(chars):
    '''Reverse of the above function. Will work regardless of whether
    url_safe was set to True or False.'''
    # Make sure the data is in binary type.
    if isinstance(chars, six.string_types):
        chars = chars.encode('utf8')
    # Do the reverse of the url_safe conversion above.
    chars = chars.replace(b"-", b"/").replace(b".", b"+")
    # First decode the base64, adding the required "=" padding.
    b64_pad_len = 4 - len(chars) % 4
    decoded = base64.b64decode(chars + b"="*b64_pad_len)
    # Now decode little endian with "0" padding, which are leading zeros.
    int64_pad_len = 8 - len(decoded)
    return struct.unpack("<Q", decoded + b'\x00' * int64_pad_len)[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do following conversions by using python

First of all import base64 by using following syntax

```
>>> import base64
```

For converting **text to base64** do following

encoding

```
>>> base64.b64encode("cloth".encode()).decode()
    'Y2xvdGg='
```

decoding

```
>>> base64.b64decode("Y2xvdGg=".encode()).decode()
    'cloth'
```

Comment: This doesnt answer my question! I need to change 427021005928 into 'Y2xvdGg='. I do not have the value 'Y2xvdGg=' at the start